# symfony doctrine query is not working

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

i have a ManyToMany relation between 2 entities Guest and Party :

```
//Prif\ProtocoleBundle\Entity\Guest

/**
 * @var string
 * 
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Prif\ProtocoleBundle\Entity\Party", cascade={"persist"})
 * 
 */
private $parties;
```

i made a form where i can add many parties to a Guest with checkboxes

```
  \\Prif\ProtocoleBundle\Form\GuestType

  public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
    $builder

            ->add('name', 'text', array(
                'required'=>true))

            ->add('firstname', 'text', array(
                'required'=>true)) 

            ->add('parties', 'entity', array(
                'class' => 'PrifProtocoleBundle:Party',
                'property' => 'name',
                'expanded' => true,
                'multiple' => true,
                'required'=>false
            ))
```

Then i made a search form (PartySearchType)  where i can select one or many parties. and when i submit this form i want to have the guests that have been added to those parties

## This is my search function in the repository

```
//Prif\ProtocoleBundle\Entity\GuestRepository
/**
 * Summary
 * @param   object  $name_parties           Description
 * 
 * @return  object                  Description
 */
public function searchGuestByParty(array $name_parties) {

    $query = $this->createQueryBuilder('g');

        $query->Join('g.parties', 'p')
              ->where($query->expr()->in('p.name', $name_parties));


        return $query->getQuery()
                ->getResult();
```

## My search Action in the controller

```
/**
 * @Route("/", name="guest)
 * @Template()
 */
public function searchAction(Request $request) {
    $entity = new Guest();

    $form = $this->createForm(new PartySearchType(), $entity);

    if ($request->getMethod() == 'POST') {
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        $parties = $form['parties']->getData();
        //var_dump($parties) this var_dump shows me a result of selected parties
            $repository = $this->getDoctrine()
                    ->getManager()
                    ->getRepository('PrifProtocoleBundle:Guest');

            $guests = $repository->searchGuestByParty(array($parties));
            //var_dump($guests) this var_dump shows me: array (size=0) empty;

            return $this->render('PrifProtocoleBundle:Guest:result.html.twig', array(
                        'entities' => $guests,
                            )
            );
    }
    return array(
        'form' => $form->createView(),
    );
}

}
```

## result of var_dump($guests):

```
array (size=0) empty
```

## part of the twig view

```
\\result.html.twig

{% block body -%}
<h1>List of guests </h1>
<table class="records_list">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>name</th>
            <th>surname</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    {% for entity in entities %}
        <tr >
            <td>{{ entity.name }}</td>
            <td>{{ entity.surname }}</td>
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
</table>
{% endblock %}
```

## My problem:

i'm not sure of my query in GuestRepository function, and of the way i call it in the controller, coz when i make a var_dump on it i don't get no results.
so the view is empty! can someone take a look at the code and tell me what's wrong? thanks for your time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## i've changed the repository function, now it works!

it retrieves the guests according to the parties selected in the form

```
public function searchGuestByParty($parties) {

    $name_parties = array();


    for($i = 0; $i < count($parties); ++$i){

        $name_parties[$i]= $parties[$i]->getName();
    }

    $query = $this->createQueryBuilder('g');

    $query->Join('g.parties', 'p')
          ->where($query->expr()->in('p.Name', $name_parties));


    return $query->getQuery()
                    ->getResult();
}
```

## the search action in the controller doesn't change much

```
public function searchAction(Request $request) {
$entity = new Guest();

$form = $this->createForm(new PartySearchType(), $entity);

if ($request->getMethod() == 'POST') {
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    $parties = $form['parties']->getData();

        $repository = $this->getDoctrine()
                ->getManager()
                ->getRepository('PrifProtocoleBundle:Guest');

        $guests = $repository->searchGuestByParty($parties);


        return $this->render('PrifProtocoleBundle:Guest:result.html.twig', array(
                    'entities' => $guests,
                        )
        );
}
return array(
    'form' => $form->createView(),
);
```

}

}

Answer (score 0):

At first glance, it appears you are passing $name_parties to searchGuestByParty but in the where clause you are using $nom_name_parties, an uninitialized variable.  Could it be that simple?

Comment: hi, thanks for reply. this is a just a typing error that i did! coz i've translate it from french to english for this question. changed that!

Comment: this is the result of var_dump($guests): array (size=0) empty (maybe it can help, thanks)